# Registry.GetValue Error. C# in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am attempting to get a value from the registry in order to complete a print function using crystal reports.

But it errors out when I do the path because my registry path isn't working properly.

```
     Values- Global.gAPPNAME = "TEST" Global.gAPPSECTION = "STARTUP"

     Global.gREPORTDIR = Registry.GetValue(Global.gAPPNAME, Global.gAPPSECTION, "REPORTDIR").ToString();
```

When it hits the Global.gREPORTDIR line I get the error - "registry key name must start with a valid base key name"

I am new to this and I was wondering whether this is something that can be fixed with code or something I need to find within the actual computer to find the correct path. Any advice would help. Thanks.

Comment: Use the RegistryKey class to fall in the pit of success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify a valid root name:

> Valid root names are `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`,
>   `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, `HKEY_USERS`, `HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA`,
>   `HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG`, and `HKEY_DYN_DATA`.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to add a key to Global.gAPPName which result in bypassing the current error but now i get  a null exception error on that line.

Comment: It's sard to say with out seeing the current code but if you do a ToString() on a null, you get that exception.

Comment: We decided instead of trying the read the registry to just create an xml file to store the values and read/write from that. That way it will also allow us to change back and forth from xp and win7. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about Registry.GetValue here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue.aspx

So your error comes from first parameter:

> Valid root names are HKEY_CURRENT_USER, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
>   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, HKEY_USERS, HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA,
>   HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG, and HKEY_DYN_DATA. For example, in Visual Basic
>   the string "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\MyTestKey" accesses key/value pairs for
>   the subkey "MyTestKey" in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER root.

You can use static keys for easy use

```
Registry.LocalMachine.Name
```

Comment: Your answer comes across as a little snarky there, sir.

Comment: Rather than challenging if they have read the documentation, tell them what's wrong and provide the documentation as evidence for your reasoning.